# Formatting being lost on a shiny app when using column

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny dashboard where i am using a tab Panel and in that panel I'm trying to place two summary tables side by side

The tables seem to lose the background of the tabPanel

Does anyone know why

Reproducible example below

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
data(iris)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$top_Length = renderTable({

    mydf <-  iris %>%
      arrange(desc(Sepal.Length)) %>% 
      slice(1:10)


    mydf

  })  

  output$top_width = renderTable({

    mydf <-  iris %>%
      arrange(desc(Sepal.Width)) %>% 
      slice(1:10)

  })  

   }


header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Flower Power")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE)

 body <- dashboardBody(fluidRow(

  tabBox(title = "Charting Information",width = 9,
     tabPanel("Trending"),
     tabPanel("Details",
              column(4,
                     h2('Top Sepal Length'),
                     tableOutput('top_Length')
              ),

              column(3,
                     h2('Top Sepal Width'),
                     tableOutput('top_width')    
              )

     )
     )
))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin = "yellow",
  header,
  sidebar,
  body
)  


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fluidRow` to prevent overlapping as below:

```
            fluidRow(  column(4,
                     h2('Top Sepal Length'),
                     tableOutput('top_Length',width="200")
              ),

                 column(3,
                     h2('Top Sepal Width'),
                     tableOutput('top_width')  )  
              )
```

Comment: Hi @Erdem Akkas, Does the `fluidRow` go inside the `tabPanel`. I need the tabs present but just cut the content for brevity. The overlapping im ok with as this is just a very rough draft. In essence they should go next to each other but should remain apart of the `tabPanel`

Comment: With this structure they are both a part of `tabPanel` and should be side by side.